# Nice diophantine equations with large smallest solutions

Tags: nt.number-theory, big-list, diophantine-equations

Given a polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients in finitely many variables,
we denote by $v(P)$ the product of the absolute values of the non-zero coefficients
and the non-zero total degrees of the monomials of $P$.

Since there is no general algorithm to decide whether an equation
$P(x_1, \dots, x_k) = 0$ has a solution in integers $x_1, \dots, x_k$ or not,
for every computable function $f$ there is a polynomial $P$ such that
the equation $P(x_1, \dots, x_k) = 0$ has such solution, but none for which
all $x_i$ have absolute value less than $f(v(P))$.
In particular, this holds for the function $f: n \mapsto 2^n$.

For the purposes of this question, we say that the diophantine equation
$P(x_1, \dots, x_k) = 0$ has *large smallest solution* if it has a solution,
but none such that all $x_i$ have absolute value less than $2^{v(P)}$.

**Question:** Which are ''nice'' examples of diophantine equations
with large smallest solution?

Here are some non-examples:

- Put $P := x-1$. Then, $v(P) = 1$, but the equation $P(x) = 0$
  has the solution $x = 1$ whose absolute value is less than
  $2^{v(P)} = 2^1 = 2$.
- Put $P := a^2 + b^2 - c^2$. Then, $v(P) = 2^3 = 8$,
  hence our bound is $2^8 = 256$. Even not counting the solution
  $a = b = c = 0$, there is e.g. the solution $a = 3, b = 4, c = 5$
  where all values are less than $256$.
- Put $P := x^2 - 61y^2 - 1$. Then, $v(P) = 2^2 \cdot 61 = 244$,
  and the solution $(x,y) = (1766319049,226153980)$ is clearly less than
  the bound of $2^{244} > 10^{73}$.
- Put $P := a^4 + b^4 + c^4 - d^4$. Then, $v(P) = 4^4 = 256$,
  hence our bound is $2^{256}$. Even not counting the solution
  $a = b = c = d = 0$, there is e.g. the solution $a = 95800$,
  $b = 217519$, $c = 414560$, $d = 422481$,
  where all values are less than $2^{256} > 10^{77}$.
- Put $P := x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 33$. Then, $v(P) = 3^3 \cdot 33 = 891$,
  and the absolute values of all numbers in the solution
  $$
      (x,y,z) = (−2736111468807040,−8778405442862239,8866128975287528)
    $$
  are clearly less than the bound of $2^{891} > 10^{268}$.
- Now, let's have a look at the equation
  $$
      \frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} + \frac{c}{a+b} \ = \ 4.
    $$
  This truely has a [large smallest solution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315969/),
  at least if one insists on $a$, $b$ and $c$ being positive, hasn't it? —

  No, not really: subtracting 4 from both sides of the equation, and multiplying
  the equation by the common denominator of the terms, we arrive at the polynomial
  $$
      P = a^3-3a^2b-3a^2c-3ab^2-5abc-3ac^2+b^3-3b^2c-3bc^2+c^3,
    $$
  which has
  $$
      v(P) = 3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3
             \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3 = 215233605.
    $$
  We observe that the smallest solution even doesn't exceed $2^{267}$,
  let alone $2^{215233605}$.

**Addendum:** In order to further explain what I mean by ''nice'' in this context:
while it is straightforward to build equations which in some obvious ways encode
computations which yield large numbers, the art is rather to find equations which
do not do so in any obvious way (like the non-examples above), but which still
satisfy the condition on the size of the smallest solution. — And these latter
equations are rather the ones which are ''nice'' in the sense of this question.
Nevertheless, in case no good such examples are found, also the equations of the
former type are valid answers to the question (just not such good ones).

Comment: Is the intention in the question to allow equations where we consider only positive solutions or only nonzero solutions, as you do in some of the examples?

Comment: @WillSawin Nice examples are welcome in any case. Just the smallest solution (respectively, smallest non-zero or smallest positive solution, if applicable) should exceed the given bound.

Comment: If I typed it right, $(x^2-((a+C)^2-1)y^2-1)^2+(u^2-((a+C)^2-1)v^2-1)^2+(s^2-(b^2-1)t^2-1)^2+(v-ry^2)^2+(b-1-4py)^2+(b-a-C+qu)^2+(s-x-cu)^2+(t-k-4(d-1)y)^2+(y-k+e-1)^2 + (x^{'2}-(x^2-1)y^{'2}-1)^2 + (u^{'2} - (x^2-1)v^{'2}-1)^2 + (s^{'2}-(b^{'2}-1)t^{'2}-1)^2+ (v'-r'y^{'2})^2 + (b'-1-rp'y')^2 + (b'-x-q'u')^2 +(s'-x' - c'u')^2 +(t'-k'-4(d'-1)y')^2$ with the restriction that $a$ is positive does the trick for all sufficiently large $C$.

Comment: (By Theorem 3.1 of Hilbert's Tenth problem is unsolvable by Martin Davis, this equation, if I typed it right, forces $x$ to be exponentially large as a function of $a+C$ and $x'$ to be exponentially large as a function of $x$, so if $a$ is positive then $x'$ is double-exponential as a function of $C$, but $v$ is merely polynomial in $C$.)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466362/can-9xy-divide-1x2x3y2#comment1210512_466362 This is a nice equation with large minimal solutions.

Comment: @DenisShatrov If I counted right that has $v(P)= 324$ but the solution in that question is merely of size $\approx 2^{140}$, so not large enough.

Comment: @WillSawin Yes, I calculated $v(P)$ wrongly.

Comment: @DenisShatrov If the smallest solution would be large enough, that equation would make an excellent answer to the question.

Comment: When you write "has such solution", what does "such" refer to?  Do you mean "has a solution"?

Comment: $(x_1-2)^2  + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (x_i^2 - x_{i+1})^2$ doesn't meet your requirements, but arguably it gets somewhat "close".  The smallest solution has size $2^{2^k}$, and $v(P) = 32 \times 48^{k-1}$.

Comment: Some very large numbers come up in smallest solutions to problems in the thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514/conjectures-that-have-been-disproved-with-extremely-large-counterexamples I don't know what those problems would look like if you turned them into diophantine equations. Likewise, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15444/examples-of-eventual-counterexamples

Answer (score 7):

A better example: I believe conjecturally the equation $(a-N)^2 + (b-a^2)^2 + (c-b^2)^2 + (d-c^2)^2 + (x^2 - (d+a-1) y^2+1)^2 $ in the variables $a,b,c,d,x,y$, with $N$ fixed, should do the trick for most values of $N$.

We have $v(P) =2^{29} 3^8 5^4 N^3$.

The first few terms force $d= N^8$ and the last term gives the negative Pell's equation $x^2- (N^8+N- 1)y^2=-1$. This is solvable for a majority of integers by [work of Koymans and Pagano On Stevenson's Conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.13424) and there is no reason to suspect the proportion is much different for integers of the form $N^8+N-1$ (in particular, since $N^8+N-1$ is an irreducible polynomial).

The least solution of Pell's equation is of size roughly exp of the square root of the discriminant as long as the class group is not too large, which it is under the natural restriction of the Cohen-Lenstra conjecture to a polynomial subsequence of discriminants.

So you just have to take $N$ large enough that exp of $N$ to the fourth power beats exp of $N$ to the third power times a rather large constant, so $N$ very roughly on the order of $2^{29} 3^8 5^4  \approx 2,000,000,000,000,000$ should work.

Comment: Well — but doesn't the Pell equation in this always have the solution $(x,y) = (N^4,1)$, or did I misread something?

Comment: @StefanKohl Right, true. Sufficiently many minor adjustments should make that disappear, e.g. This one with $N^8-1$ might be OK. One might need to take $N^8 + N + 1$ or something like that, which is a much nicer polynomial for this sort of thing.